# Wiring new ceiling fan with only one hot wire and a remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

What happens if I connected the two hot wires that were powering a ceiling fan and light together when replacing with a new ceiling fan with remote that had only one hot wired. I put all three in one cap. Is this dangerous?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you wedded to the remote that came with your ceiling-fan?

Comment: Ok I am replacing them with more modern looking ones

Comment: The fan or the remote?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two switches feeding two switched hots and you want to connect both of these to the fan supply wire.

This is **probably** safe and will result in either switch being able to turn on the fan.

There is a small chance that these wires are on a multi-wire branch circuit and the hots are on opposite 120 volt legs. In this case, doing that will cause a short circuit and hopefully trip the breakers.

I’d recommend, just for general principles, to use just one hot wire and cap the other.

Comment: I should add that there are two fan/lights operating off a single wall switch and both set to the same remote frequency. Now that I have replaced one fan the remote works and the switch still kills both. Interestingly the old remote no longer works on the other, old fan. Is there a chance I robbed the receiver on the old fan of its power without robbing the fan itself?